# Toggle Tab Closes itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've implemented a tab bar that slides from right to left. It uses simple JQuery and a bit of CSS for Styling.

I've applied it to the whole site. Unfortunately when I open then close it and go to the next page to repeat the same the tab closes itself. Do you have an idea what might be causing the issue?

```js
///////
///Settings object
///////
var settings = {
    objSlideTrigger: '.trigger',
    objSlidePanel: '.panel'
  }
  ///////
  ///Slide out tab
  ///////

function slideOutTab() {
  //Bind a click handler to the trigger
  $(settings.objSlideTrigger).bind('click', function() {
    //If the panel isn't out
    if (!$(settings.objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')) {
      //Animate it to left 0px
      $(settings.objSlidePanel).animate({
        'right': '0px'
      });
      //Add the out class
      $(settings.objSlidePanel).addClass('out');
    } else {
      //Otherwise, animate it back in
      $(settings.objSlidePanel).animate({
        'right': '-300px'
      });
      //Remove the out class
      $(settings.objSlidePanel).removeClass('out');
    }
  });
}
$(function() {
  slideOutTab();
});
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qqL9g41n/1/)

Comment: fiddle is working great. i can't see the closing of tab. It opens on click and if open it closes on click. can you say if am missing something

Comment: Yes, you can not replicate in the fiddle. It is when navigating from one page to another. It seems to add a class that triggers the button to close itself.

Comment: wow how come that... means when you navigate to next page... then the tab on the previous page closes, right?

Comment: 1. First page - tab works fine , 2. Second page - click on tab and it closes itself after

Comment: are they live on internet? means can i see them?

Comment: No unfortunately they are on my local host

Comment: there might be some class issue... may be it already have the class `.out`

Comment: I thought the same change the class and it still triggers the odd behaviour

Comment: Can you re-create on local server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104556/discussion-between-kanudo-and-john).